# Multilabel number classification TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, numbers, multilabel-classification

I´d like to have this kind of an app. I have an ArrayList1<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...> Each unique number from ArrayList1 is feature in my model. Now I have another ArrayList2<6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16..>. This ArrayList2 will be labels, but it´s multilabel classifier. I don´t mind if binary/fuzzy multilabel classifier. Is it possible to do that within Tflow(TF is important-I will use it within Android= TfLite or Bytedeco java)? If so, please link me: 1, Github code 2, courses 3, books 4, articles etc. Thank you. Also i am sorry for my english and lack of TF knowledge. I am just foreign developer, I know nearly nothing about ML, but i know college Maths. Thank you guys. It´s something like TensorFlow for poets image net, but with numbers instead of images.

Comment: You can convert the labels to one-hot encoding and then use a regular Dense layer at tf.keras.layers.Dense

Comment: Thank you. And if i want to do this?

I have this table:

Index/// Feature/// Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4
00/// 1/// 1, 0, 0, 0
01/// 2/// 2, 0, 0, 0
02/// 2/// 1, 1, 0, 0
03/// 3/// 0, 3, 0, 0
04/// 2/// 1, 1, 0, 0
.......

 Now I want to predict Output(Label1+Label2+Label3+Label4)  for input (2=feature) but based on previous inputs. Do we have already written code for this task in TFlow? Thank you.